# python: how to configure multiple loggers to log to same file

Tags: python-logging

I have three loggers logging to the same file

**Case1** here i have defined handler only once and added it to all loggers later. It shows the correct results

```
import pytz
import datetime
import logging
class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    """override logging.Formatter to use an aware datetime object"""
    def converter(self, timestamp):
        #dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        #we use
        dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        current_time_utc = pytz.utc.localize(dt)
        tzinfo = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
        current_time_time_zone = current_time_utc.astimezone(tzinfo)
        #print(current_time_time_zone)
        return current_time_time_zone
        
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        dt = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = dt.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            try:
                s = dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
            except TypeError:
                s = dt.isoformat()
        return s


import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


filename1 = "./file.log"

handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename1, mode='a', maxBytes=400, backupCount=10, encoding='utf-8', delay=0)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(Formatter("\n%(asctime)s:::%(levelname)-8s:::%(message)s"))


# logger1
logger1 = logging.getLogger('name1')
logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger1.addHandler(handler)

#logger2
logger2 = logging.getLogger('name2')
logger2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger2.addHandler(handler)

#logger3
logger3 = logging.getLogger('name3')
logger3.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger3.addHandler(handler) 

for i in range(0,100):
    logger1.info("form logging1")
    logger2.info("form logging2")
    logger3.info("form logging3")


# run this command to concatenate the logs
# python test.py; find ./ -name "file.*" | sort -r -V | xargs awk '(FNR==1){print ">> " FILENAME " <<"}1' > all_logs_test.txt
```

results: all logs contenated

```
>> ./file.log.10 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.229-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.229-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.229-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.229-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.230-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.230-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.9 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.230-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.230-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.230-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.230-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.230-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.231-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.8 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.231-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.231-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.231-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.231-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.231-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.231-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.7 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.232-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.232-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.232-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.232-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.233-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.233-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.6 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.233-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.233-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.233-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.234-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.234-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.234-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.5 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.234-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.234-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.235-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.235-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.235-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.235-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.4 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.235-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.236-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.236-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.236-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.236-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.236-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.3 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.237-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.237-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.237-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.237-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.237-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.237-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.2 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.238-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.238-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.238-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.238-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.238-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.238-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.1 <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.239-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.239-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.239-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:48:42.239-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.239-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.239-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log <<

2021-03-09T22:48:42.240-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:48:42.240-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:48:42.240-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
```

**case2**:

Whereas here i define handler in each and then create loggers, not showing results correctly

```
import pytz
import datetime
import logging
class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    """override logging.Formatter to use an aware datetime object"""
    def converter(self, timestamp):
        #dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        #we use
        dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        current_time_utc = pytz.utc.localize(dt)
        tzinfo = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
        current_time_time_zone = current_time_utc.astimezone(tzinfo)
        #print(current_time_time_zone)
        return current_time_time_zone
        
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        dt = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = dt.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            try:
                s = dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
            except TypeError:
                s = dt.isoformat()
        return s


import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


filename1 = "./file.log"

# logger1
logger1 = logging.getLogger('name1')
logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename1, mode='a', maxBytes=400, backupCount=10, encoding='utf-8', delay=0)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(Formatter("\n%(asctime)s:::%(levelname)-8s:::%(message)s"))
logger1.addHandler(handler)

#logger2
logger2 = logging.getLogger('name2')
logger2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename1, mode='a', maxBytes=400, backupCount=10, encoding='utf-8', delay=0)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(Formatter("\n%(asctime)s:::%(levelname)-8s:::%(message)s"))
logger2.addHandler(handler)

#logger3
logger3 = logging.getLogger('name3')
logger3.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename1, mode='a', maxBytes=400, backupCount=10, encoding='utf-8', delay=0)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(Formatter("\n%(asctime)s:::%(levelname)-8s:::%(message)s"))
logger3.addHandler(handler) 

for i in range(0,100):
    logger1.info("form logging1")
    logger2.info("form logging2")
    logger3.info("form logging3")


# run this command to concatenate
# python test_2.py; find ./ -name "file.*" | sort -r -V | xargs awk '(FNR==1){print ">> " FILENAME " <<"}1' > all_logs_test_2.txt
```

results: (when run in linux)

```
>> ./file.log.10 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.864-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.865-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.865-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.865-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.866-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.9 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.864-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.865-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.865-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.865-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.866-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1
>> ./file.log.8 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.866-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2
>> ./file.log.7 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.867-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.6 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.867-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.868-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.869-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1
>> ./file.log.5 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.869-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.871-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2
>> ./file.log.4 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.869-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.871-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.871-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.3 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.870-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.871-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.871-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1
>> ./file.log.2 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.871-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.872-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.873-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2

2021-03-09T22:42:43.873-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging2
>> ./file.log.1 <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.872-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.872-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.873-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3

2021-03-09T22:42:43.873-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log <<

2021-03-09T22:42:43.872-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.873-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1

2021-03-09T22:42:43.873-05:00::LOGGER1:::INFO    :::form logging1
```

Also when i try the second one in windows it gives the following error. It even does not give the result like above

```
the test2.py gives this error in windows

--- Logging error ---                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "C:\\Users\\dev\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\logging\\handlers.py", line 70, in emit                                                                                                                  
    self.doRollover()                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  File "C:\\Users\\dev\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\logging\\handlers.py", line 171, in doRollover                                                                                                           
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "C:\\Users\\dev\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\logging\\handlers.py", line 111, in rotate                                                                                                               
    os.rename(source, dest)                                                                                                                                                                                                
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\\\Dev\\\\Stock-chart\\\\backend_django\\\\stock\\\\cron_jobs\\\\testing2\\\\file.log' -> 'D:\\\\Dev\\\\Stock-chart\\\\backend_django\\\\stock\\\\cron_jobs\\\\testing2\\\\file.log.1'                                                                                                                                                                         
Call stack:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "testing2.py", line 65, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                 
    logger2.info("form logging2")                                                                                                                                                                                          
Message: 'form logging2'                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Arguments: ()
```

I think the results should be shown correctly in the second case also, why its behaving like that.

Where `Case1` is not practical way to define three loggers seperately

Whereas `Case2` is more practical to define each logger in a seperate function

So coding point of view `Case2` is more practical. Like i can have three functions, pass the filename and they will create three loggers

Answer (score 0):

What is working for me to have multiple loggers log to single file without hicups and also using rotationfilehandler.

I wanted to use to for module level. BUt i found that it keeps duplicating the logs. So this helped me to avoid that

```
    for hdlr in logger.handlers[:]:  # remove all old handlers
        logger.removeHandler(hdlr)
```

the final working code

so i have logging_config.py

```
import pytz
import datetime
import logging

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
def create_handler(filename):
    #filename1 = "./file.log"
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename, mode='a', maxBytes=1000, backupCount=10, encoding='utf-8', delay=0)
    #handler = logging.FileHandler(filename,mode='a')
    return handler

# we have different logger to have differnt formats. here it may look all are same and of no use
# to create three. Like we can have sepearte logger for sql and requests and normal logging
def get_logger1(handler):
    logger1 = logging.getLogger('name1')
    logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    for hdlr in logger1.handlers[:]:  # remove all old handlers
        logger1.removeHandler(hdlr)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("\n%(asctime)s:::%(levelname)-8s:::%(message)s"))
    logger1.addHandler(handler)

    return logger1

def get_logger2(handler):
    logger2 = logging.getLogger('name2')
    logger2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    for hdlr in logger2.handlers[:]:  # remove all old handlers
        logger2.removeHandler(hdlr)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("\n%(asctime)s:::%(levelname)-8s:::%(message)s"))
    logger2.addHandler(handler)
    return logger2


def get_logger3(handler):
    logger3 = logging.getLogger('name3')
    logger3.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    for hdlr in logger3.handlers[:]:  # remove all old handlers
        logger3.removeHandler(hdlr)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("\n%(asctime)s:::%(levelname)-8s:::%(message)s"))
    logger3.addHandler(handler)
    return logger3
```

test1.py

```
import time
from test2 import logger_test
from logging_config import get_logger1, get_logger2, get_logger3, create_handler
import logging

handler = create_handler("file.log")
logger1 = get_logger1(handler)
logger2 = get_logger2(handler)
logger3 = get_logger3(handler)


for i in range(0,10):
    logger1.info("form logging1")
    time.sleep(1)
    logger2.info("form logging2")
    time.sleep(1)
    logger3.info("form logging3")
    time.sleep(1)
    logger_test()
```

test2.py

```
import time
from logging_config import get_logger1, get_logger2, get_logger3, create_handler
import logging


from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

handler = create_handler("file.log")
logger1 = get_logger1(handler)
logger2 = get_logger2(handler)
logger3 = get_logger3(handler)

def logger_test():
    logger1.info("form logging1 another file")
    time.sleep(1)
    logger2.info("form logging2 another file")
    time.sleep(1)
    logger3.info("form logging3 another file")
    time.sleep(1)
```

and eveything is printed in sequence in multiple files

```
>> ./file.log.3 <<
2021-03-10T02:10:56.657-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:10:57.659-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:10:58.661-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:10:59.663-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:00.666-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:01.667-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:02.669-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:03.671-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:04.673-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:11:05.674-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:06.676-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:07.678-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:08.680-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:09.681-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:10.683-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log.2 <<
2021-03-10T02:11:11.686-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:12.687-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:13.688-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:14.690-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:15.692-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:16.695-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:11:17.697-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:18.699-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:19.701-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:20.703-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:21.704-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:22.706-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:11:23.707-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:24.709-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:25.711-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
>> ./file.log.1 <<
2021-03-10T02:11:26.713-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:27.715-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:28.717-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:11:29.719-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:30.721-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:31.723-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:32.724-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:33.726-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:34.728-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:11:35.729-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:36.730-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:37.732-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:38.734-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:39.735-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:40.737-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
>> ./file.log <<
2021-03-10T02:11:41.740-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:42.741-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:43.743-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:44.744-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:45.746-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:46.748-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:11:47.749-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:48.751-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:49.752-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:50.754-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1
2021-03-10T02:11:51.756-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2
2021-03-10T02:11:52.758-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3
2021-03-10T02:11:53.760-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging1 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:54.761-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging2 another file
2021-03-10T02:11:55.763-05:00:::INFO    :::form logging3 another file
```